# Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce removed basket items not shown in dashboard

Tags: google-analytics

I have a function to remove an item from my analytics data. I'm calling the below function, when my shopper deletes an item from their cart. I've followed the example in the docs.

```
function removeFromCart(product) {
  ga('ec:addProduct', {
    'id': product.id,
    'name': product.name,
  });
  ga('ec:setAction', 'remove');
  ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'remove from cart');
}
```

I was expecting the *Product Adds To Basket* metric to decrement by 1 when this function is called, but it appears to remain the same.

[image]

Is this a wrong assumption? Is there a *Product Removes From Basket* column that I need to reveal in the dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this information in this report in Google Analytics:

[image]